# How to make Kafka distribute the data equally among all partitions with multiple keys?

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, unique-key

A Kafka topic was created with 10 partitions and producer produced multiple messages with 12 different keys (labeled key_1, key_2, key_3, ... , key_10).
It was observed that all the messages were sent to only 2 partitions with most of the messages in one of the partition and remaining few in another partition. 8 out of 10 partitions remained empty.
How to make Kafka distribute the data equally among all 10 partitions based on the keys ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write your own partitioner class to make even distribution a guarantee.

Otherwise, the computed hashes of the keys you sent, modulo'd by the number of partitions, might only be binned into 2 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 12 distinct keys and 10 partitions it is impossible to get uniform distribution based on key values. The reason is simple: partitioner is a function and {f(key1), f(key2), ..., f(key12)} is a subset of {p1, p2, ..., p8} where some partitions may not be present and some may be present multiple times.

You have following choices:

- Write custom partitioner that maps keys 1-10 to partitions 1-10 and keys 11, 12 to partitions 1, 2. Additionally you can increase number of partitions to 12 instead of 10 and rewrite your partitioner so that it will put each key into its own partition.
- Remove key from your messages so round robin algorithm is used. However messages with the same key (that is gone now) may and will get into different partitions.
- (trash one) Write your one partitioner that ignores message key and puts message into random partition, for example, in a round robin way.

For details on how to implement partitioner try to look for kafka's default one org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner on github.